# Where to put angular ng-templates in django project

Tags: javascript, angularjs, django, templates

I have lots of `ng-template`s like this:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="item.html">
     // content
</script>
```

Now, all of them are in one `base.html` file and thus the template code has become messy.

I want to put each ng-template in its own html file.

Logical place would be `templates` folder. But when I tried to reference templates like `templates/ng-templates/item.html`, I got `404 Not Found`.

How can I fix it? Or, what is the best practice of accomplishing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually you should place your angular templates to the static directory.
Because Django doesn't serve templates, it uses those for rendering.

So, for example you could place your template in `/static/templates/item.html`, and in angular you reference this template like `/{{ STATIC_URL }}/templates/item.html`.

Comment: Is that good practice to put templates inside static directory?

Comment: @AshrafulIslam Firstly usually those are templates related to front-end components. Secondly, this is the most flexible way (you can use template cache, minimization, webpack/gulp/whatever). So, I would say that it's completely acceptable to keep front-end related templates inside static directory.

Comment: I think it's security issue. Because you can access every static files with example.com/static/test.html. And thanks for your answer.